# group rows based on 'date time distance'

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Let us say I have rows containing data like this:

```
2014-10-28 08:25:00
2014-10-28 10:25:00
2014-10-28 10:30:00
2014-11-03 09:25:00
2014-11-03 09:40:00
2014-11-03 09:40:00
2014-11-10 09:40:00
2014-11-17 09:25:00
```

Depending on some predefined 'date time distance' (e.g. 120 minutes) one could group these data time values:

into 4 groups:

```
2014-10-28 08:25:00
2014-10-28 10:25:00
2014-10-28 10:30:00

2014-11-03 09:25:00
2014-11-03 09:40:00
2014-11-03 09:40:00

2014-11-10 09:40:00

2014-11-17 09:25:00
```

Can something like this be achieved via TSQL. I tried something along those [lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994862/date-difference-between-consecutive-rows) but it is not the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query would be simpler in SQL Server 2012, but in 2008 you could use a couple of common table expressions to indicate all "jumps" of more than 2 hours with a '1', then do a simple running total over the result;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT dt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt) rn FROM mytable
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT a.dt, CASE WHEN b.dt is null THEN 1 END z
  FROM cte a
  LEFT JOIN cte b
    ON a.rn = b.rn + 1 AND DATEDIFF(mi, b.dt, a.dt) <= 120
)
SELECT dt, (SELECT SUM(z) FROM cte2 c WHERE c.dt <= cte2.dt) grp
FROM cte2
ORDER BY dt
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8e82/2).

Comment: Thanks. Ill have a look tomorrow.