# How to compare datetime NextRow with CurrentRow in SQL and find a difference in X amount of days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, compare, datediff

This is my current table structure (MS SQL 10):

```
CaseNo     EntryDate                    Comment
0000000001     2013-10-10 12:00:00.000      This is a test comment
0000000001     2013-10-21 18:00:00.000      This is a test comment
0000000002     2013-10-10 12:00:00.000      This is a test comment
0000000003     2013-11-07 12:00:00.000      This is a test comment
0000000003     2013-12-01 02:00:00.000      This is a test comment
0000000003     2013-12-01 09:00:00.000      This is a test comment
0000000004     2013-10-10 12:00:00.000      This is a test comment
```

Expected output:

```
CaseNo
0000000001
0000000003
```

What I'm looking for is to get a list of CaseNos where the activity (Comment) between entry dates is more than 7 days apart (one instance is enough).

This is where I'm currently at (taken from [Date Difference between consecutive rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994862/date-difference-between-consecutive-rows)):

```
SELECT  T1.CaseNo, 
    T1.Operator, 
    T1.EntryDate, 
    MIN(T2.EntryDate) AS NextDate, 
    DATEDIFF("D", T1.EntryDate, MIN(T2.EntryDate)) AS DaysDiff
FROM    CaseCorrespondence T1
    LEFT JOIN Cases T2
        ON T1.CaseNo = T2.CaseNo
        AND T2.EntryDate > T1.EntryDate
GROUP BY T1.CaseNo, T1.Operator, T1.EntryDate
ORDER BY T1.CaseNo;
```

The problem with this query is that I'm not currently calculating where T1.EntryDate is older than x days.  The DaysDiff column will tell me how many days exist between rows, but I cannot seem to add a WHERE clause to this to specify > 7 days.  (WHERE DaysDiff > 7) for example

Comment: Since you are comparing dates, it would be beneficial to know which database you are using.

Comment: Sounds like you are using `SQL Server 2008`, so unfortunately, you won't be able to take advantage of the new analytic functions like `Lead` and `Lag` functions which was introduced in `SQL Server 2012`. But you could use `row_number` instead to do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create sample table:**

```
create table cases (CaseNo varchar(50),    EntryDate datetime,    Comment varchar(255));

insert into cases values
('0000000001', '2013-10-10 12:00:00.000', 'This is a test comment'),
('0000000001', '2013-10-21 18:00:00.000', 'This is a test comment'),
('0000000002', '2013-10-10 12:00:00.000', 'This is a test comment'),
('0000000003', '2013-11-07 12:00:00.000', 'This is a test comment'),
('0000000003', '2013-12-01 02:00:00.000', 'This is a test comment'),
('0000000003', '2013-12-01 09:00:00.000', 'This is a test comment'),
('0000000004', '2013-10-10 12:00:00.000', 'This is a test comment');
```

You could use `ROW_NUMBER()` to do this:

```
;WITH q1
AS (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY caseno ORDER BY caseno
                ,entrydate
            ) AS rn
        ,c.*
    FROM cases c
    )
SELECT q1.caseno
FROM q1
INNER JOIN q1 q2 ON q1.caseno = q2.caseno
    AND q1.rn = q2.rn + 1
WHERE datediff(day, q2.entrydate, q1.entrydate) > 7
```

**Result:**

```
+------------+
|   caseno   |
+------------+
| 0000000001 |
| 0000000003 |
+------------+
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3e7e/10/0)