# SPARK, DataFrame: difference of Timestamp columns over consecutive rows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DateFrame as follow:

```
+---+---------------------+---------------------+
|id |initDate             |endDate              |
+---+---------------------+---------------------+
|138|2016-04-15 00:00:00.0|2016-04-28 00:00:00.0|
|138|2016-05-09 00:00:00.0|2016-05-23 00:00:00.0|
|138|2016-06-04 00:00:00.0|2016-06-18 00:00:00.0|
|138|2016-06-18 00:00:00.0|2016-07-02 00:00:00.0|
|138|2016-07-09 00:00:00.0|2016-07-23 00:00:00.0|
|138|2016-07-27 00:00:00.0|2016-08-10 00:00:00.0|
|138|2016-08-18 00:00:00.0|2016-09-01 00:00:00.0|
|138|2016-09-13 00:00:00.0|2016-09-27 00:00:00.0|
|138|2016-10-04 00:00:00.0|null                 |
+---+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The rows are ordered by `id` then `initDate` column in ascending order.
Both `initDate` and `endDate` columns have Timestamp type. For illustrative purpose, I just showed the records belonging to one `id` value.

My goal is to add a new column, showing **for each `id` the difference (in term of days) between the `initDate` of each row and the `endDate` of the previous row**.

If there is no previous row, then the value will be -1.

The output should look like this:

```
+---+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|id |initDate             |endDate              |difference|
+---+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|138|2016-04-15 00:00:00.0|2016-04-28 00:00:00.0|-1        |
|138|2016-05-09 00:00:00.0|2016-05-23 00:00:00.0|11        |
|138|2016-06-04 00:00:00.0|2016-06-18 00:00:00.0|12        |
|138|2016-06-18 00:00:00.0|2016-07-02 00:00:00.0|0         |
|138|2016-07-09 00:00:00.0|2016-07-23 00:00:00.0|7         |
|138|2016-07-27 00:00:00.0|2016-08-10 00:00:00.0|4         |
|138|2016-08-18 00:00:00.0|2016-09-01 00:00:00.0|8         |
|138|2016-09-13 00:00:00.0|2016-09-27 00:00:00.0|12        |
|138|2016-10-04 00:00:00.0|null                 |7         |
+---+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

I am thinking to use a window function to partition the records by `id`, but I am not figuring how to do the next steps.

Comment: Why do you want to find the difference between initdate of current row and end date of previous row on manually sorted records?

Comment: Yes, what do you mean by "manually" sorted records? The records are sorted no matter if manually or not.

Comment: Well, I need to calculate this difference, I am asking if there is a way to calculate it. It is equivalent to calculating the difference between the endDate of the current row and the initDate of the next one.

Comment: Can you store the DF as temp table and try to write a query like in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994862/date-difference-between-consecutive-rows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of @lostInOverflow, I came up with the following solution:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("initDate")
val previousEnd = lag($"endDate", 1).over(w)
filteredDF.withColumn("prev", previousEnd)
          .withColumn("difference", datediff($"initDate", $"prev"))
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("endDate")

df.withColumn("difference", date_sub($"initDate", lag($"endDate", 1).over(w)))
```

Comment: Doesn't date_sub take the second argument being number of days? I think datediff is the function needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to previously good answers, in case anyone wants to try with spark sql or on Hive.

```
select tab.tran_id,tab.init_date,tab.end_date,coalesce(tab.day_diff,-1)
as day_diffrence from
(select *,datediff(day,lag(end_date,1) over(partition by tran_id order by init_date)
,init_date) as day_diff from your_table) tab
;
```