# Get biggest difference in successive timestamps with additional constraint?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `items` which represents moving items. Among others, this table has the PK `name`, the timestamp `creation_time` which contains the time of the creation of the entry and the string `type` which can either be `start`, `move` or `end` with `move` entries coming inbetween `start` and `end`.

A part of the table may look like this:

```
name creation_time       type
_________________________________
i1   2017-03-01 10:00:01 start
i1   2017-03-01 10:00:02 move
i1   2017-03-01 10:00:08 move
i1   2017-03-01 10:00:10 end
i1   2017-03-01 10:00:31 start
i1   2017-03-01 10:00:33 move
i1   2017-03-01 10:00:37 end
```

What I want to get is the biggest difference(s) of successive timestamps where the type of the second timestamp is not `start` (I do not care for the times between an `end` and a `start`).

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994862/date-difference-between-consecutive-rows) I've come with the following query which does not yet take into account the type of the entries:

```
select name, creation, next_creation, (next_creation-creation) difference from (
  select name, creation, (
    select min(creation) from items i2
    where i2.name=i.name
    and i2.creation > i.creation
  ) as next_creation
  from items i
)
where (next_creation-creation) is not null
order by difference desc
```

My problem is that I don't know how to properly filter for the type now. To my understanding, I'd have to get the type from the innermost query, because I care for the type of the second entry, and then add `and type<>'start'` to the where clause of the outermost query - but I can't get two values from the subquery, right?

Edit: The results I expect would look like this:

```
name creation            next_creation        difference action
i1   2017-03-01 10:00:02 2017-03-01 10:00:08  6s         move
i1   2017-03-01 10:00:33 2017-03-01 10:00:37  4s         end
[...]
```

As you see, there is no entry for the time between the first `end` and the second `start`, that's what want to accomplish by filtering for the type.

There is also, for example, no entry for the time between the very first and very last entry because I want the difference between successive entries.

Comment: Please show us how the final result of the query should look like.

Comment: You need the max difference for each name value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question prior to its edit:

Use the [`LAG` analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm):

```
SELECT name,
       MAX( time_difference ) AS max_time_difference
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         type,
         creation_time
           - LAG( creation_time ) OVER ( PARTITION BY name ORDER BY creation_time )
           AS time_difference
  FROM   items
)
WHERE type != 'start'
GROUP BY name;
```

**Updated**

To get it for each group of start/end items (which appears to be what you expected output is showing - since it has multiple rows):

```
SELECT name,
       creation_time,
       next_creation_time,
       next_creation_time - creation_time AS difference,
       type
FROM   (
  SELECT i.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY name, start_group
           ORDER BY next_creation_time - creation_time DESC, creation_time ASC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT name,
           type,
           creation_time,
           LEAD( creation_time ) OVER ( PARTITION BY name ORDER BY creation_time )
             AS next_creation_time,
           SUM( CASE type WHEN 'start' THEN 1 END )
             OVER( PARTITION BY name ORDER BY creation_time )
             AS start_group
    FROM   items
  ) i
  WHERE type != 'end'
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! That function is exactly what I searched for, and magnitudes faster then the query I built upon.

Answer (score 0):

Per my uderstanding . This must be a inclusion of column "TYPE" in the subquery that can be used as a filter in Inline View. Hope it helps.

```
SELECT name,
  creation,
  next_creation,
  (next_creation-creation) difference
FROM
  (SELECT name,
    creation,
    (SELECT MIN(creation)
    FROM items i2
    WHERE i2.name   =i.name
    AND I2.CREATION > I.CREATION
    ) AS NEXT_CREATION,
    type
  FROM items i
  )
WHERE (NEXT_CREATION-CREATION) IS NOT NULL
and type                       <> 'start'
ORDER BY difference DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the max difference for each name value, something like that should work:

```
SELECT i1.NAME, MAX(i2.creation_time - i1.creation_time) difference
FROM items i1
INNER JOIN items i2 ON i1.name = i2.name AND i1.creation_time <= i2.creation_time
WHERE 'start' NOT IN (i1.type, i2.type)
GROUP BY i1.name;
```