# Alias Reference Date_Diff Days. Need to Parse or create temp table with dates?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Below I have the tables and query which output the below

Table1

```
EmployeeID | StartDateTimestamp | CohortID | CohortName
---------- | ------------------ | -------- | ----------
1          | 20080101 01:30:00  | 1        | Peanut
1          | 20090204 01:01:00  | 2        | Apple
2          | 20190107 05:52:14  | 1        | Peanut
3          | 20190311 02:35:26  | 2        | Apple
```

Employee

```
EmployeeID | HireStartName | StartDateTimestamp2
---------- | ------------- | -------------------
1          | HiredStart    | 20080501 01:30:00
1          | DeferredStart | 20090604 01:01:00
2          | HiredStart    | 20190115 05:52:14
3          | HiredStart    | 20190330 02:35:26
```

Query

```
select 
    t.cohortid, 
    min(e.startdatetimestamp2) first,  
    max(e.startdatetimestamp2) last

from table1 t
inner join employee e on e.employeeid = t.employeeid
group by t.cohort_id
```

Output

```
ID | FIRST            | LAST
1  |20190106 12:00:05 |20180214 03:45:12
2  |20180230 01:45:23 |20180315 01:45:23
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT DATE_DIFF(first, last, Day), ID, max(datecolumn1) first, min(datecolumn1) last
```

Error: Unrecognized name.
How do I enter the reference alias first and last in a Date_Diff?
Do I need to derive a table?

Clarity: Trying to avoid inputting in the dates, since I am looking to find the date diff of both first and last columns for as many rows as there is data.

This answer has been discussed here: [Date Difference between consecutive rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994862/date-difference-between-consecutive-rows])

DateDiff has deprecated, and now it is Date_Diff (first, last, day)

Then I tried:

```
SELECT ID, DATE_DIFF(PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d',t.first), PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d',t.last), DAY) days
FROM table
```

Failed to parse input string "20180125 01:00:05"

Tried this

```
SELECT CohortID, date_diff(first,last,day) as days
FROM (select cohortid,min(startdatetimestamp2) first, 
max(startdatetimestamp2) last 
FROM employee 
JOIN table1 on table1.employeeid = employee.employeeid 
group by cohortid)
```

I get days not found on either side of join

Comment: what exactly your question is? can you please clarify

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant

Trying to calculate the number of days in between the first and last columns.

Comment: present example of your data so we can help

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant

Why doesn't this work?:
```select 
    t.cohortid, 
    min(e.startdatetimestamp2) first,  
    max(e.startdatetimestamp2) last,
    date_diff(first, last, day) days

from table1 t
inner join employee e on e.employeeid = t.employeeid
group by t.cohort_id```

Comment: @RoastedCarrot you can not use column aliases in the same SELECT list, thats why above query will not work. You can write subqueries and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question about using aliases in a query, there are some restriction where to use them, specially in the ***FROM***, ***GROUP BY*** and ***ORDER BY*** statements. I encourage you to have a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#aliases_2) to check these restrictions.

About your main issue, obtaining the date difference between two dates. I would like to point that your timestamp data, in both of your tables, are actually considered as ***DATETIME*** format in BigQuery. Therefore, you should use ***DATETIME*** builtin functions to get the desired results.

The below query uses the data you provided to obtain the aimed output.

```
WITH
  data AS 
  (
  SELECT
    t.cohortid AS ID,
    PARSE_DATETIME('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S', MIN(e.startdatetimestamp2)) AS first,
    PARSE_DATETIME('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S', MAX(e.startdatetimestamp2)) AS last
  FROM
    `test-proj-261014.sample.table1` t
  INNER JOIN
    `test-proj-261014.sample.employee` e
  ON
    e.employeeid = t.employeeid
  GROUP BY t.cohortid 
  )
SELECT
  ID,
  first,
  last,
  DATETIME_DIFF(last, first, DAY ) AS diff_days
FROM
  data
```

And the output:

[image]

Notice that I created a temp table to format the fields *StartDateTimestamp* and *StartDateTimestamp2*, using the [PARSE_DATETIME()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#parse_datetime). Afterwards, I used the [DATETIME_DIFF()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#datetime_diff) method to obtain the difference in days between the two fields.